# Best Practices for API calls in strongloop loopback

Tags: angularjs, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have created the models in loopback which are accessible via rest and I am using the rest calls in AngularJS like this.

```
 $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/staffs').
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.facultymembers = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     alert("Error!: "+ status );
   });
```

is this good practice? please suggest any better way if its not a best way...

Comment: It appears that Loopback doesn't have best practices. They have a framework but do not have best practices of utilizing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using the LoopBack Angular SDK. It'll help you automatically set up the services that will communicate with your REST API. See my example here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-angular

Answer (score 1):

yes its a good way to call service but if all of our endpoints are RESTful then its better to use `$resource` then `$http`.

**Advantage**
if you use $http then to get all the staffs details you will call

```
 $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/staffs').
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.facultymembers = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     alert("Error!: "+ status );
   });
```

to get the detail of specific staff

```
   $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/staffs?id=' + id).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.facultymembers = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         alert("Error!: "+ status );
       });
```

but if you use $resource

then just create a factory

```
      angular.module('myApp.services').factory('staff', function($resource){
              return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/staffs/:id'); 
        });
```

and then to get all the staff details call

```
staff.query(function(data){

});
```

get the detail of specific staff by

```
staff.get({id:'123'},function(data){

})
```

Comment: `LoopBack Angular SDK` does this exactly.